# Image visibility stopped working in Windows Phone 8.1 after xamarin.forms upgrade

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms app, On main page a list of items are displayed. A checkbox image is made visible when user selects an item from the list. Image visibility is toggled when user taps on an item, to give user the impression that item has been selected.

This functionality was working fine in all platforms i.e. iOs, Android, WP8.1. But once when I upgraded my xamarin forms version from 1.5X to 2.X, The checkbox image stoped appearing in windows phone when user select an item. Although in iOs and android its working fine.

*If I downgrade the xamarin forms back to version 1.5, functionality works fine.*

**I also discovered that when app starts in windows phone, If we rotate the screen horizontally, the checkbox image starts functioning again. But that's just a hack!!!**

For the checkbox functionality I have used the following code -

```
/// <summary>
/// A selectable cross-platform cell
/// </summary>
public class CustomSelectableCell : ViewCell
{
    private Grid _gridLayout;
    private Label _text;
    private Image _image;

    /// <summary>
    /// The BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSelectableCell, Command>(i => i.Command, default(Command));
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets the command which gets executed on tapped
    /// </summary>
    public Command Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (Command)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Then BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty AutoSelectProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSelectableCell, bool>(i => i.AutoSelect, true, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets if the cell will automatically select the itself by tapping
    /// </summary>
    public bool AutoSelect
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(AutoSelectProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(AutoSelectProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSelectableCell, bool>(i => i.IsSelected, default(bool), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, IsSelectedChanged);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets if the cell is in selected state or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSelectableCell, string>(i => i.Text, default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, TextChanged);
    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets/Sets the text of the cell
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of <c>CustomSelectableCell</c>
    /// </summary>
    public CustomSelectableCell()
    {
        this._gridLayout = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions = 
            { 
                new RowDefinition 
                { 
                    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) 
                }
            },
            ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
                new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                },
                new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
                }
            }
        };

        this._image = new Image
        {
            Source = "ic_done_white_24dp.png",
            IsVisible = false
        };
        this._text = new Label
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle
        };

        this._gridLayout.Children.Add(this._text, 0, 0);
        this._gridLayout.Children.Add(this._image, 1, 0);

        this.View = this._gridLayout;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when <c>IsSelected</c> changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The cell</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Old value</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">New value</param>
    private static void IsSelectedChanged(BindableObject obj, bool oldValue, bool newValue)
    {
        var cell = obj as CustomSelectableCell;

        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell._image.IsVisible = newValue;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the <c>Text</c> changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The cell</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Old value</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">New value</param>
    private static void TextChanged(BindableObject obj, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        var cell = obj as CustomSelectableCell;

        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell._text.Text = newValue;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Auto Select on tapped
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnTapped()
    {
        base.OnTapped();

        if (this.AutoSelect)
        {
            this.IsSelected = !this.IsSelected;
        }
        if (this.Command != null)
        {
            if (this.Command.CanExecute(this))
            {
                this.Command.Execute(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help it get resolved??? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Jkm

Comment: Why this question is put on hold?, It clearly states how to reproduce this issue... Its a genuine question.

Comment: The large friendly beige banner above  (created 21 hours ago) clearly explains everything. As of 19 minutes ago your question didn't contain _any_ code.

Comment: Hi Micky, I am not sure why you are not able to see the code, But I can see the code I have put inside my Question. Please check again. I hope I can add something more if you want.

Comment: I'm saying _I can_ see the code now. I am nominating that your question be _re-opened_.  Thank-you for improving your question by adding the code.  Cheers